# Generate pem pkcs8 with key rsa nodejs

Tags: node.js, openssl, rsa, pem

I have a .key file with password and I need to get the .pem file with RSA PKCS8 method with NodeJS function.

The command I use to do it with OpenSSL is the following

`openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -out file.pem -passin pass:passwordkey`

Comment: ... and what is the problem?

Comment: how to do it in nodejs

Comment: do you resolve this?